# Commutativity of addition in polymorphic lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-systems, polymorphism, typed-lambda-calculus

In the article "Extensional models of polymorphism" by Breazu-Tannen and Coquand, natural numbers are presented using a Church-like encoding:

$polyint = \forall t . (t \to t) \to t \to t$

Addition for this encoding is introduced as:

$\mathsf{Add} = \lambda u,v : polyint . \Lambda t . \lambda f : t \to t . \lambda x : t . u t f (v t f x)$

Then they say that commutativity of addition cannot be proved, and they say that $\mathsf{Add} u v = \mathsf{Add} v u$ does not follow from polymorphic lambda calculus theory by a simple Church-Rosser argument. What's this Church-Rosser argument? Is it related to the Church-rosser property? How can I prove it?

EDIT: the exact statement is:

"However, the pure $\lambda^{\forall}$ is not sufficient for that, as it cannot even prove, for example, that the operation of addition is commutative:

$\mathsf{Add}\ u\  v = \mathsf{Add}\ v\ u$

with arbitrary $u, v : polyint$ is not provable in $\lambda^{\forall}$ (by a simple Church-Rosser argument)".

Comment: I would imagine they are talking about the fact that the polymorphic $\lambda$-calculus is strongly normalizing.

Comment: How would strong normalization imply the assertion?

Comment: It wouldn't, and that's what they are saying, as you write yourself: "does *not* follow from the Church-Rosser argument". Other things do follow, for example the fact that $\mathsf{Add}\,u\,z = u$ where $z = \Lambda t \lambda f x . x$ is "zero" is obtained by reducing all $\beta$-redexes on the left-hand side.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the assertion that says that "it does not follow that ...". How is that $\mathsf{Add} u v = \mathsf{Add} v u$ contradicts strong normalization?

Comment: It doesn't *contradict* CR, it just doesn't "trivially follow" from it. In general, to prove commutativity, you need some kind of characterization of *all* possible normal forms of each argument. It is possible to build models in which, for example, there are some elements of type $polyint$ that are not of the form $S(S(\ldots S(0)\ldots)$, and so the equation may not hold in those models.

Comment: I've edited the question to cite exactly the authors. They affirm that commutativity is not provable in polymorphic lambda calculus. I understand that they say that that it can be shown not to be provable by a simple Church-Rosser argument. How do they prove the non-provability of commutativity?

Comment: @AndrejBauer, just a remark: it seems to me that you are confusing Church-Rosser (which is essentially the transitivity of $\beta$-equality) with (strong) normalization.

Comment: @cody: what you say is absolutely true but I think is not what Breazu-Tannen and Coquand are saying. Their point (which has been made explicit by the OP's last comment) is that the fact that the equality is *not* provable is itself provable using Church-Rosser.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Count me as confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that $\mathsf{Add}\ u\ v = \mathsf{Add}\ v\ u$ is not provable for arbitrary $u$ and $v$ does indeed follow from the Church-Rosser property.

Write $u =_\beta v$ if $u \mathrel{({}_\beta\!\!\leftarrow\cup\rightarrow_\beta)^\ast} v$, where $\rightarrow_\beta$ is $\beta$-reduction in System F and $(\cdot)^\ast$ is the reflexive-transitive closure operator (this is a possible definition of $\beta$-equality, which Breazu-Tannen and Coquand denote simply by $=$. Here I will use the $\beta$ subscript and keep the $=$ symbol for strict equality, i.e., $\alpha$-equivalence if you like).  It follows immediately from the definition that if two terms have a common reduct, i.e., $u\rightarrow_\beta^\ast w$ and $v\rightarrow_\beta^\ast w$, then $u=_\beta v$. The Church-Rosser theorem states that the converse also holds:
$$u=_\beta v \quad \textrm{implies}\quad \exists w.\ u\rightarrow^\ast w\textrm{ and }v\rightarrow^\ast w.$$
It follows that $\beta$-equivalent normal forms are necessarily identical:
$$u,v\textrm{ normal and }u=_\beta v\textrm{ implies }u=v.$$

Read contrapositively, the above says that different normal forms can never be $\beta$-equivalent. Now, suppose $\mathsf{Add}\ u\ v=_\beta\mathsf{Add}\ v\ u$ for arbitrary $u$, $v$. In particular, this holds when $u=x$ and $v=y$ are distinct variables of type $polyint$. But it is easy to show (just apply a couple of steps of $\rightarrow_\beta$) that $\mathsf{Add}\ x\ y=_\beta u'$ and $\mathsf{Add}\ y\ x=_\beta v'$ with $u'$ and $v'$ distinct normal forms. Contradiction.